# MVC 3 razor custom webhelper how to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using MVC3 Beta and I would like to know how could I create my library of custom WebHelpers and reuse them either in my project or in other projects, kind of like the Microsoft NuGet web helper.
In other words something like HTML Helpers in MVC2.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source code for MVC 3 and WebPages here http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/54306 and use that as a guide for your own project.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman has a very nice post on [How to create a NuGet package in 7 easy steps](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx).